# FCM delivery status behavior

Tags: android, firebase, go, xmpp, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app server written in GO language is sending notifications to the device through FCM / XMPP. When i set delivery_receipt_requested to true, i am not receiving delivery status message every time.

For testing purposes, i made test app that sends push notification every second with delivery_receipt_requested to true. For 10 notifications, i am receiving only two or three (sometimes not even one) delivery status message, and on android app all notifications are delivered.

I tried two FCM / XMPP Go libraries, but both of them have same behavior ([Go-FCM](https://github.com/mcilloni/go-fcm), [Soygul GCM](https://github.com/soygul/gcm))

On android device, latest Google Play Services are used (at the moment 10.2.4)

Is this common behavior, or am i missing something?

Comment: Hi Zeljko. Could you post your Android side code and Server side related code?

Comment: It seems that problem was in invalid JSON configuration on Android side.. Problem solved.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, the problem was in invalid JSON configuration on Android side. It is used same bundle id for two projects..